# Does Agile Web Development With Ruby on Rails (Third Edition) Create Bad Coding Habits?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Does *Agile Web Development With Ruby on Rails (Third Edition)* teach best practices as well as Rails coding?

My concern is that, as I use this book, I'm developing bad Rails coding habits resulting from the rather basic nature of the examples used in the book. Case-in-point:

**The Product Model:**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.find_products_for_sale
  find(:all, :order => "title" )
end
```

**The Store Controller**

```
class StoreController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @products = Product.find_products_for_sale
  end
end
```

**The Store Index View**

```
<h1>Your Pragmatic Catalog</h1>
<% @products.each do |product| -%>
  <div class="entry">
  <%= image_tag(product.image_url) %>
  <h3><%=h product.title %></h3>
  <%= product.description %>
  <div class="price-line">
  <span class="price"><%= product.price %></span>
  </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Is it a best practice to declare a 'helper' function of sorts just to pull in all the available products in the catalog? Shouldn't they have just done this?

`@products = Products.find(:all, :order => "title")`;

I understand that they were probably just trying to demonstrate class-level methods, but they don't add any caveat in the code stating that this isn't *really* how you're supposed to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in this particular you could have done that.

But sometimes when doing complex finds, its better to abstract into a custom find statement. Applying model specific business rules etc, should be done inside the model instead of the controller. So its not exactly a bad idea.

You can even use named_scopes to do the similar things. check out for this for more

http://railscasts.com/episodes/108-named-scope

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak for the entirety of the book, but from your example, I don't find that to be a bad coding habit, but a good one.

It's not really a helper method, it's a specific query on your `Product` class and should be named/declared as such.

In the future, should you need to change the functionality of how `find_products_for_sale` works—I find this naming a little weird, I prefer `for_sale`—then you can do that in the model and not have to touch your controller at all. If you have multiple actions in your controller that are using `find_products_for_sale` then you've effectively saved yourself a bunch of typing/potential headaches.

There are now `named_scope`s (and as of Rails 3, just `scope`) for these types of things which is a nicer way of stating them.